# How to send multpart/form-data file along with other form parameters in ruby net/http?

Tags: ruby, multipartform-data, net-http

I want to upload a file using **POST** method having a content type of `multipart/form-data` along with other form parameters. I have tried with this code but I'm getting an error.

```
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

url = URI.parse('https:action/upload-v1/file')
File.open("rough.txt") do |text|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new url.path,
    "file" => UploadIO.new(text, "text/plain", "rough.txt")

    req.basic_auth 'nikhil', 'Lee'

    req.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    req.use_ssl = true
    req.set_form_data('deviceId' => '2366', 'checksum' => '132654798', 'fileSize' => '1260', 'fileType' => 'configuration', 'compressionType' => 'Z')
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
    response = http.request(req)
    puts response.body

  end
end
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Ruby193>ruby TestMultipart.rb
TestMultipart.rb:10:in `block in <main>': undefined method `verify_mode=' for #<Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart POST> (NoMethodError)
        from TestMultipart.rb:4:in `open'
        from TestMultipart.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

url = URI.parse('https:action/upload-v1/file')
File.open("rough.txt") do |text|
    "file" => UploadIO.new(text, "text/plain", "rough.txt")
    req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new url.path
    req.basic_auth 'nikhil', 'Lee'
    req.set_form_data('deviceId' => '2366', 'checksum' => '132654798', 'fileSize' => '1260', 'fileType' => 'configuration', 'compressionType' => 'Z')
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https') do |http|
       http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
       response = http.request(req)
       puts response.body
  end
end
```

Comment: I use the above code but now i am getting another error saying :C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:673:in `use_ssl=': use_ssl value changed, but session already started (IOError)
        from TestMultipart.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:746:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:557:in `start'
        from TestMultipart.rb:10:in `block in <main>'
        from TestMultipart.rb:4:in `open'
        from TestMultipart.rb:4:in `<main>'

Comment: I fixed, please try again.

Comment: C:\Ruby193>ruby TestMultipart.rb
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:673:in `use_ssl=': use_ssl value changed, but session already started (IOError)
        from TestMultipart.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:746:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:557:in `start'
        from TestMultipart.rb:11:in `block in <main>'
        from TestMultipart.rb:5:in `open'
        from TestMultipart.rb:5:in `<main>'

Comment: you change `http.use_ssl = true` to `http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == "https")`?

Comment: i think we should not start HTTP connection before setting use_ssl

Comment: No, i think it was your change

Comment: can you try this: `res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https') do |http|...`

Comment: It worked for me the error has gone but my parameters are not getting submitted.

Comment: yes, i tried your solution but my set_form_data is not going with my request